# How can I alter this code in order to get a result no matter if I put a string or integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to alter the following code in order for it to accept both integers and strings. Which means get a result no matter if I put '21' or 21

```
import random

class Game(object):

    def __init__(self, lower, higher):
        self.lower_limit = lower
        self.upper_limit = higher
        self.number = random.randrange(self.lower_limit, self.upper_limit)


    def guess(self, num):
        if (num) < self.__number:
            print("Die Zahl ist zu klein!")

        elif (num) > self.__number:
            print("Die Zahl ist zu groß!")

        else:
            print("Bingo!!!")


    def get_lower (self):
        return self.__lower_limit

    def get_upper(self):
        return self.__upper_limit

    lower_limit = property (_get_lower_limit, _set_lower_limit)
    upper_limit = property (_get_upper_limit, _set_upper_limit)

g = Game(0,20)

while True:

    try:
        n = input("Which number? ")
        g.guess(int(n))

    except ValueError:
        print("not an integer")

print(g.guess)
```

Comment: Does not your code already do the convert?

Comment: `input` is *already* a string, it's not clear to me what additional behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: You want to support added quotes in the user input?

Comment: If i press enter on the code it asks me of course to give a number in order to start excecuting. All fine when I enter for example 4. Now I wanna make it work even when I enter '4' or "4" too

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to int in your init part

```
self.lower_limit = int(lower)
self.upper_limit = int(higher)
```

You already cast the parameter:

```
g.guess(int(n))
```

Now this it not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
n = int() function for lines where number come from your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by default as string using str().strip("'") and then use int()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable users to enter string literals containing integer numbers, you could add a call to `ast.literal_eval()` before attempting to convert it to an integer:

```
import ast
s1 = "'21'"
s2 = "21"
print(int(ast.literal_eval(s1))) # prints 21
print(int(ast.literal_eval(s2))) # prints 21
```

You might need to catch a few other exceptions for different error cases in the user input though (e.g., `ValueError`, `SyntaxError`, maybe more).

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval